# hdfs dfs commands: failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

Whenever I run any `hdfs dfs` commands I am getting `Call From hostnamehere/10.138.238.104 to hostnamehere:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused`

I have searched online a lot for a solution but everyone seems to offer the same few solutions and none of them has worked for me. I have tried the following:

`stop-dfs.sh` and `start-dfs.sh` --- this didn't help

`stop-dfs.sh` and `hadoop namenode -format` then `start-dfs.sh` --- this fixes it for about 5mins (I can run `hdfs dfs` commands) then it will go back to the `ConnectException` error.

Double checked my `core-site.xml` and other hadoop .xml configs to make sure they are correct (exact same configs as another working hdfs cluster)

Checked `/etc/hosts` to make sure hosts and hostnames are correct.

`systemctl stop/start hadoop` --- didn't help

From all the things I tried the only method that worked temporarily was doing `hadoop namenode -format`, but it only fixed it for about 5mins, then it breaks again. Does anyone have other suggestions? I am mostly confused because how can it work for a few minutes then not work? This must imply the configs are correct because otherwise it would never work even once right?

Comment: ok, but after 5 min, is still there the namenode daemon?? use `jps` to look for the process

Comment: No, `jps` does not have those processes, and the port 9000 is also not open...somehow they are only available for a few minutes, which is the root issue I think

Comment: something is killing those processes, that's why you can't keep connected

Comment: this is in the cloud or you're running an on promise cluster?

Comment: on DigitalOcean, and how can I debug this if something is killing my processes?

Comment: ok, it must with tracing log of the hdfs, i don't remember very well which is the file, let my review my notes

Comment: please, and thank you

Comment: http://www.hadoopadmin.co.in/bigdata/how-to-enable-debug-logging-for-hdfs/

Comment: Basically, follow that blog

Comment: Doing debug mode gives me a similar error ```2020-05-22 07:47:00,338 DEBUG ipc.Client: IPC Client (1292040526) connection to /IPADDRHERE:9000 from root: closed
2020-05-22 07:47:00,368 DEBUG retry.RetryInvocationHandler: Exception while invoking call #0 ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.getFileInfo over null. Not retrying because try once and fail.```
And Googling this error leads me to the same solutions as mentioned in the original parent post...`stop-all.sh` and things like that, which still only fixes it for about 5mins before breaking...

Comment: hey, have you solved the problem?

Comment: No unfortunately, still same issue as described

Answer (score 0):

check your /etc/hosts
check your core-site.xml , make sure that your ip is same as your hdfs：//ip：8020
and stop-dfs.sh start-dfs.sh
ok